# How to fill Authentication Required popup in chrome with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to open a intranet website with Selenium which redirects to another link for login and gets back to original URL on valid login. For example - When I start webdriver and navigate to original site URL `https://DemoOriginalWebsite.Com` the browser gets redirected to `https://Validateyourselfbeforeaccessing.com:9030` and shows below popup window to enter user id and password.

[image: Popup window]

I tried to pass credentials as below but didn't work.

**Try 1 :** http://username:pswd@DemoOriginalWebsite.Com

**Try 2 :** https://username:pswdValidateyourselfbeforeaccessing.com:9030

The authentication URL can't be accessed directly.

My actual code:

```
IWebDriver chromeDriver;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);        
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
chromeDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();     chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://username:pswd@DemoOriginalWebsite.Com");
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use AutoIT. Install AutoIT, write the script in AutoIT and export it as an .exe file. This .exe you will have to call in your selenium

```
WinWait("Untitled - Google Chrome", "" , 10)) //This will wait for 10 seconds for window with the specified title
WinActivate("Untitled - Google Chrome"); // This will send the focus of the cursor to the window with the specified title
Send("username");

//1st argument : moves the cursor's focus from Username textbox to Password text box.  
//2nd argument : false,  over here tell that it is not a text but raw key
Send("{TAB}", false); 
Send("password");
Send("{Enter}", false);// this will mimic the action of pressing enter button.
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: Cool bro. AutoIT is amazing as you are. I have changed web-driver to Internet Explorer as it gives me proper windows popup. Will be adding my working code for reference to readers. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that I could be of some help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I figured out.

1 - Added AutoIt NuGet package to project.

2 - Used as below:

```
IWebDriver driverIE = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driverIE.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driverIE.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://DemoOriginalWebsite.Com");
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Windows Security", "", "Edit1");
AutoItX.ControlSetText("Windows Security", "", "Edit1","userid");
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Windows Security", "", "Edit2");
AutoItX.ControlSetText("Windows Security", "", "Edit2", "password");
AutoItX.ControlClick("Windows Security", "", "Button2");
//Do your work.
driverIE.Dispose();
```

Tutorials I followed. 
[Tutorial 1](https://youtu.be/51iuVOHGUHs) and [Tutorial 2](https://youtu.be/civzNtKTCD0)